# Git folder not removed after renaming it

Tags: git, directory

I have renamed a folder with git mv from A to B.
On git only B is present.

Now when I pull to update the repo from my other laptop I can see the new folder B but A is still there.

git status tells me everything is in sync. Even editing a file inside folder A has no effect and git does not see any changes like A is a ghost folder now.

How can I reset the git repo on my second laptop to tell it to discard this ghost folder without having to checkout again the repo to have a clean state?

Comment: check the SHA's on github and locally.  If folder A is still there locally something is obv wrong.  Make sure your .gitconfig doesn't have any relevant settings affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [git clean documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean). This command does the following:

> ...Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not
>   under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the -x option
>   is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example,
>   be useful to remove all build products...

If you're looking to remove an empty directory, I would do 
`git clean -fd`. If you're looking to remove everything that isn't tracked in the repo try `git clean -fxd`